# QML: Unable to assign [undefined] to

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to rewrite interface for a Qt-Android program from QWidgets to QML. I never used it earlier so mistakes could be very obvious and dumb.

New interface is based on ListView:

It looks like:

```
ListView
{
    id: listView
    x: 16
    y: 146
    width: 262
    height: 282
    model: myModel
    delegate: Item
    {
        x: 5
        width: 80
        height: 40
        Row
        {
            id: row1
            spacing: 10
            Text
            {
                width: 50
                text:model.modelData.getPassword
                font.bold: true
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }
            ProgressBar
            {
                value: model.modelData.getDifficulty
            }
        }
    }
}
```

List in main() is filled this way:

```
QList<QObject*> dataList;
dataList.append(new DataObject("Item 1", 50));
dataList.append(new DataObject("Item 2", 60));
dataList.append(new DataObject("Item 3", 70));
dataList.append(new DataObject("Item 4", 80));


QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
qmlRegisterType<BackEnd>("tk.asciigames.backend", 1, 0, "BackEnd");

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant::fromValue(dataList));

engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

return app.exec();
```

DataObject:

```
class DataObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString password         READ getPassword)
    Q_PROPERTY(unsigned int difficulty  READ getDifficulty)
public:
   DataObject(QString _pass, unsigned int _difficulty)
{
    difficulty = _difficulty;
    password = _pass;
}

QString getPassword()
{
    return password;
}

unsigned int getDifficulty()
{
    return difficulty;
}

private:
unsigned int    difficulty;
QString         password;

};
```

While running QML really shows 4 lines(as expected) but without data.
Log has such errors:

```
qrc:/main.qml:118:26: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString
qrc:/main.qml:124:28: Unable to assign [undefined] to double
```

Those errors corresponds to QML-lines:

```
text:model.modelData.getPassword
value: model.modelData.getDifficulty
```

So it looks like QML gets the array but not able to get data from it.

Can somebody help me to find a mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you declare the Q_PROPERTY, you define a name, and a getter function. The getter function is used by the c++ to get the actual value of the property, but the QML engine has no knowledge of it ; it only knows the property name (`password` in this example)

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString password READ getPassword)
```

So, in your QML file, change the lines

```
text:model.modelData.getPassword
value: model.modelData.getDifficulty
```

to

```
text:model.modelData.password
value: model.modelData.difficulty
```

And you should be good to go.

Note that you can also use a shortened syntax to access the properties

```
value: model.modelData.difficulty // OK
value: model.difficulty // OK
value: modelData.difficulty // OK
value: difficulty // Still OK
value: model.model.model.model.model.modelData.difficulty // OK, but don't do that
```

You may also want to flag your Q_PROPERTY as CONSTANT, to get rid of the warning `QQmlExpression: Expression qrc:/main.qml:25:20 depends on non-NOTIFYable properties:`

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString password READ getPassword CONSTANT)
```

Comment: So my question really was "very obvious and dumb". It works now. Thank you.

Comment: `value: model.model.model.model.model.modelData.difficulty // OK, but don't do that` => Perfect!